# Making a re-sizable flash player

Tags: jquery, flash

One time I was watching a flash video, and it was a really small size, so I inspected element and changed the dimensions.

This gave me an idea to  make a flash player with a jquery slider that will make the size of the player adjustable.

Is there anything in web programming anywhere that is able to edit code real time the way the inspect element does it? I want to make this re-sizable flash player.

Comment: This definitely is no 'answer', but I believe JavaScript has the ability to change the HTML code of a loaded page. That way, you can resize the flash player...but that won't change the resolution of the video, so you may get pixelated results.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite happily use JavaScript to change the dimensions of the embedded `<object>` tag, either using jQuery with the `height()` and `width()` methods, or natively in JavaScript using 
`window.getComputedStyle([element]).getPropertyValue('height')`.

Whether your video will then scale successfully to the size of its `<object>` will probably depend on how you've coded up the SWF. For example, a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5yJA/) seems to scale with no problems using the JWPlayer.